# Change footer in Follow up reports

Tags: odoo-15, odoo-accounting

I need to change footer text in follow up reports - both email and print version.

Data contained in it is coming from Company details - phone, email and website URL. I wasn't able to find file where it can be changed to something else. Only file I found is in **Reports > Print > Follow-up Letter > Views** and there is no footer info in it. How can this be changed - I need fixed text here not the Phone, email and website URL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer on Odoo Forum.

1. Settings > Technical > Views
2. Search for "mail_notification_light" view
3. down in the architecture, you will see the FOOTER section

Be careful this will be applied to all emails.